# Not all content showing up after uploading to live server

Tags: theming, nodes, 7

I have been working on a site for a client and I have ran into a bit of an issue. I built the site locally and then pushed it to a staging server to show the client and everything is running fine. When we got to the point of launching the site, we did what our team normally does and everything seems to be working fine until you look at the page content... It only shows the first sentence.

Here is an example of what's going on:

staging server:[image: staging server]

live server:[image: live server]

My head is hurting from trying to figure this one out. I am using a custom theme and using  to display the data on the left hand side like we always do, so that shouldn't be the problem. I am just at a loss, any little help would be awesome!

Comment: do u have devel module ?

Comment: do u check all of the file ( template) uploaded correctly? I suggest you   change the theme for a drupal default and check it,

Comment: @zhilevan I do not have the devel module installed and I am going to try that now.

Comment: @zhilevan I set the theme to Bartik and the content is showing up the same way. Do you think it could be a database problem? When you go to edit the copy, it shows all the content.

Comment: if it shows the complete node on edit, it should not be database proble

Comment: I wonder if you can share the site url.

Comment: @arpitr it is the complete node. I did just get an error that I haven't encountered before: Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in drupal_build_js_cache() (line 4943 of /www2/avalonweddingsbcs/includes/common.inc).

Comment: @arpitr the test server is: avalonbcs.tmgdev.co/venue (warning, it's a little slow) live server: avalonweddingsbcs.com/venue

Comment: @MichaelNichols checking

Comment: can you try disabling your js aggregation

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/1802394

Comment: @arpitr I disabled the js aggregation and cleared my cache and ran cron... nothing.

Comment: @MichaelNichols do you have chat access on skype or somewhere else?

Comment: @arpitr yes, skype:mumptastic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a control character that would remain or be not there when moving from one platform to another. Line breaks in Windows, UNIX and Macintosh text files all are different. If you have moved the database from one platform to another care should be taken to insure cr lf couplets are considered.

A similar situation could result from a database conversion that did not take into account these differences.

Comment: A quick test would be to go to the edit screen change to plain text, copy that text and then paste into a text editor like notepad++ for Windows or other like product. Then look for control characters by changing code types. The characters in question should be following the text that is visible in the "viewed" node.

Comment: If the above testing shows where the problem is and you want a quick fix - you can go to each page with the problem and do the process as described but delete each incidence of the culprit character (if one is missing you would need to provide such instead of deleting) and then re-paste the text back into the node in plain text mode.  This could be quicker than finding the cause of problem and re-porting the data.

You could then locate the misstep and insure future moves that are similar are processed properly.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I ended up taking the content and editing it in my text editor. When I did that I noticed that it was adding ETX next to the text, once I took that out and reposted the content it worked! Thanks for all y'alls help on my first post!

Answer (score 0):

I think  the problem isn't about themes, I think the problem occur form database's data, If you can  export live database and test  it in another instance of local version and if them problem exist in it, I tell you upload good version of database version to live database again.